# Alphabetically order with header in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, ecmascript-6

I have a list of items fetched through API which is sorted in alphabetical order, but I want to add header above the list items. For example like below HTML Structure

```
<h4> A</h4 >
<ul>
    <li>Apple</li>
    <li>Ant</li>
</ul>
<h4>B</h4>
<ul>
    <li>Babel</li>
    <li>Ball</li>
</ul>
```

**So far I have mapped the list of items like below in function:**

```
filterItems = (itemList) => {
    result = result.map((item, index) => (
        <li className="brand-item" key={index}><a href="#">
            <img onError={this.nobrandimage} src={item.thumbnail} className="img-responsive" /></a>
        </li>
    ))
    return result;
}
```

**Below is my render function:**

```
render(){
    //code to get the letterkey, I am not sure how to put this in map function to render**
    var letters = '', groups = {};
    for (var i = 0, len; i < len; i++) {
        var letterKey = brands[i].name.charAt(0).toLowerCase(); // get the first letter
        if (letters.indexOf(letterKey) === -1) {
            letters += letterKey;
            groups[letterKey] = [brands[i]];
        } else {
            groups[letterKey].push([brands[i]]);
        }
    };

    console.log(letters);

    let brands = this.props.brands.all_brands
    if (brands) brands.sort(this.dynamicSort("name"));
    if (brands) len = brands.length
    const filteredList = this.filterItems(brands, letters);
    return (
        <ul>
            {filteredList}
        </ul>
    );
}
```

**Note: I need help to map the first letter to my list in heading tag.**

**Sample App Url to have a better view:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pfzlvo

Comment: Can you create demo to reproduce an issue?

Comment: @Justcode Please check this url for sample app https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pfzlvo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preprocess your brands into a map {letterKey: [brands]} to use in render function.

```
const groups = brands.reduce((groups, brand) => {
  const letterKey = brand.name.charAt(0).toLowerCase();
  (groups[letterKey] || (groups[letterKey] = [])).push(brand);
  return groups;
}, {});
```

Map the entries of [key, brands] to your unordered list

```
Object.entries(groups).sort().map(([letterKey, brands]) => (
  <div key={letterKey}>
    <h4>{letterKey}</h4>
    <ul>
      { brands.map(brand => <li key={brand}>{brand}</li>) }
    </ul>
</div>
));
```

```js
const brands = ['cca', 'ccb', 'ccc', 'bba', 'bbb', 'bbc', 'aaa', 'aab', 'aac'];

const groups = brands.reduce((groups, brand) => {
  const letterKey = brand.charAt(0).toLowerCase();
  (groups[letterKey] || (groups[letterKey] = [])).push(brand);
  return groups;
}, {});


Object.entries(groups).sort().map(([letterKey, brands]) => {
  console.log('KEY', letterKey);
  brands.map(brand => console.log('\tbrand', brand));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I already have a json structure which is not having key so I am generating the alphabet first letter with this `if (brands) len = brands.length
        var letters = '', groups = {};
        for (var i = 0, len; i < len; i++) {
            var letterKey = brands[i].name.charAt(0).toLowerCase(); // get the first letter
            if (letters.indexOf(letterKey) === -1) {
                letters += letterKey;
                groups[letterKey] = [brands[i]];
            } else { groups[letterKey].push([brands[i]]);
               }
        }; console.log(letters);`

Comment: I just need to map `letters` in this function which I wrote outside render `filterItems = (itemList) => {

result = result.map((item, index) => (
            <li className="brand-item" key={index}><a href="#">
                <img onError={this.nobrandimage} src={item.thumbnail} className="img-responsive" /></a>
            </li>
        ))
        return result;
    }`

Comment: Added function to process your brands into map for use in render function.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I have create one sample for my code here. Can you please have a look and suggest how can I put this because I am unable to get the data of letters outside the render function. [link] (https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pfzlvo)

Comment: Doesn't seem like that sandbox renders anything, nor do I see anything in console.  Looks like `brands` or `all_brands` is static data, just compute it in the constructor or in `componentDidMount`.  Remember, in the constructor you can set state directly, but in `componentDidMount` you have to call `setState`. There is no point in having that in the render function as it'll get recomputed on **every** render call.  In fact, that is recommended against.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I am pulling the data from API in componentDidMount. Please check this url once and you will be clear of what I am trying to do. https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pfzlvo **I am able to see the code on this url**

Comment: Still not seeing anything output, have you changed anything?  Where is `componentDidMount`?  This appears to be an incomplete component.

Comment: I am sorry, I may have changed something which affected the output. But reverted now. You can check the sample now. ( https://react-pfzlvo.stackblitz.io )

I have removed componentDidmount in the sample because I am not fetching the data from API in the sample.

Comment: You should definitely see the output something like shown in this snapshot. ( https://i.imgur.com/KcS4LPW.jpg )

Answer (score 0):

After you grouped brands `groups = {a: [apple, Ant], b: [Babel, Ball], ...}` you can iterate groups like

```
Object.keys(groups).sort().map(letter, key => (   

    <div key={key}>
        <h4>{letter}</h4>
        <ul>
            {
                groups[letter].map((word, index) => (
                    <li key={index}>{word}</li>
                ))
            }
        </ul>
    </div>


))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Object.keys(groups).map(letter, key => (   

    <div key={key}>
        <h4>{letter}</h4>
        <ul>
            {
                groups[letter].map((word, index) => (
                    <li key={index}>{word}</li>
                ))
            }
        </ul>
    </div>


))
```