# Sort list of article title and url alphabetically and group them under header using typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css

I have a list of articles about cities (name and url)-

```
const city = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Alabama',
      url: '/alabamaArticle'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Florida',
      url: '/FloridaArticle'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Denver',
      url: '/DenverArticle'
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: 'Kansas City',
      url: '/KansasCityArticle'
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      name: 'Fayetteville',
      url: '/FayettevilleArticle'
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      name: 'Austin',
      url: '/AustinArticle'
    },
  ]
```

And want to display them alphabetically side by side, grouped by their first letter.

```
<h1> A</h1 >.         <h1>D</h1>.          <h1>F</h1>

<li> Alabama </li>.   <li> Denver </li>.   <li> Florida </li>
<li> Austin </li>.                         <li> Fayetteville </li>

...
```

I have found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54071398/2248721) to be the closest to what I am trying to achieve. So I tried to modify the function from the answer

```
const [titles, setTitles] = useState(city)

  const sortedGroups: { [key: string]: string[] } = titles.reduce((sortedGroups: { [key: string]: string[] }, title: string) => {
    const letterKey: string = title.charAt(0).toLowerCase();
    (sortedGroups[letterKey] || (sortedGroups[letterKey] = [])).push(title);
    return sortedGroups;
  }, {});
```

And show the sorted cities and show them side by side using Tailwind CSS like this-

```
    <div className="grid grid-cols-4">
    Object.entries(sortedGroups).sort().map(([letterKey, titles]) => {
         sortedGroups.map((cityname:any)=>{
        return(
          <ul><h1>{letterkey}</h1></ul>
          <li key={cityname.id}>
          <Link to={cityname.url}>{cityname.name}</Link>
          </li>  
        )
      })
} 
    </div>
```

While I was able to achieve the side-by-side arrangement using CSS I need help with the typescript/javascript part. I could not make the sort function work. It seems I am doing something wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:**
I have used the suggestions from the comments and response and here is my updated code-

```
    const AlphabeticalIndex = (props:any) => {
          
          
          const sortedGroups = cities.reduce((sortedGroups:any, city) => {
            const letterKey = city.name.charAt(0).toLowerCase();
            (sortedGroups[letterKey] || (sortedGroups[letterKey] = [])).push(city);
            return sortedGroups;
          }, {});
          
          return (
            <>
           <h2 className="font-headText text-slate-400">{pageTitle} </h2>
                <hr />
             <div className="grid grid-cols-4">
            
             {Object.entries(sortedGroups).map(([groupLetter, groupCities]) => {
                 <ul><h1>{groupLetter}</h1></ul>
                 groupCities.map((city: string) => {
                  <>
                  
                  <li key={city.id}>
                  <Link to={city.url}>{city.name}</Link>
                  </li>
                  </>
                 })
               })}
          
          </div>
           
            </>
        
          )
        }
        
        
        export default AlphabeticalIndex
```

However, now I am getting this error- [image]. Any suggestion on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, I have done few changes especially to variable names :)

```js
const cities = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Alabama',
      url: '/alabamaArticle'
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Florida',
      url: '/FloridaArticle'
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Denver',
      url: '/DenverArticle'
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: 'Kansas City',
      url: '/KansasCityArticle'
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      name: 'Fayetteville',
      url: '/FayettevilleArticle'
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      name: 'Austin',
      url: '/AustinArticle'
    },
  ]

 

export function App(props) {
  const sortedGroups = cities.reduce((sortedGroups, city) => {
    const letterKey = city.name.charAt(0).toLowerCase();
    (sortedGroups[letterKey] || (sortedGroups[letterKey] = [])).push(city);
    return sortedGroups;
  }, {});

  return (
    Object.entries(sortedGroups).map(([groupLetter, groupCities]) => {
         return groupCities.map((city)=>(
          <>
          <ul><h1>{groupLetter}</h1></ul>
          <li key={city.id}>
          <Link to={city.url}>{city.name}</Link>
          </li>
          </>  
        ))
    }  
  ))      
}
```

Comment: I believe the `<h1>`, `<ul>` should be outside the inner `.map()`, but the `<li>` should be inside it, otherwise you'll get the `groupLetter` repeated for every article title within a letter group.

Comment: indeed @Wongjn, however the OP seems to only be interested in the sorting function

Comment: Ah, I see. That was verbatim code from OP and not the focus of the question, you are right. Sorry! 

Comment: @HadiElYakhni Thank you for your response. However I am getting an error "'groupCities' is of type 'unknown'."

Comment: @aries0152 ah I forgot a `return` - i just updated my answer